# Find end of FlashPlayer video using JS

Tags: javascript, flash

I have a Flash player that I created with Moyea PlayerBox and I am trying to figure out how to find out when the video is done playing. I want to create a playlist kind of like ESPN does where you can do a check box for continuous play and if it is checked I want it to keep playing if not I want the user to be able to decide where on the playlist to play.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use an external library, it looks like [JW Player](http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/wiki) supports a [MediaEvent.JWPLAYER_MEDIA_COMPLETE event](http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/wiki/Player5Events) for this.